# Start firebird backup from sql

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

In Sybase sqlAnywhere you could do:

```
BACKUP DATABASE DIRECTORY 'directory'
```

to trigger a backup.

Is there a similar solution in Firebird?

It would be easier with a sql-command, than having to distribute gbak.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SQL statement to perform a backup, you either need to use `gbak.exe`, or your application (or a companion application) needs to use the Firebird service API to perform the backup.

For example Jaybird (the Java/JDBC driver for Firebird) and the Firebird ADO.net provider implement this functionality, but it might be simpler just to include gbak.exe and call it from within your application with the right command line options.